# Finding duplicate row after failed primary key creation

Tags: mysql

Made an unsuccessful attempt to add a primary key to my table:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5);
```

Which resulted in an error message:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'FZA-M-321-FZA-M-321-300-Block, Brazil-4' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I would like to remove offending row and try again, however i'm struggling with matching this response to values in table. Reason for this is, some of the field values contain hyphen.

So, what i have is 5 initial columns used in initial, and what it seems error message containing information about 9 columns.

Is there a way to change defalut mysql delimiter or any other way around this issue?

Comment: There's no "default delimiter" between the key columns so that won't be a solution. You can find the true duplicate key values ahead of time with this query: `SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5 FROM table GROUP BY col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`. If you need more help then post the query results and add a comment so I hear about it.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing this due to some of the tables having hundreds of millions of rows. My line of thinking was to create a script that will make an attempt to add primary key and remove flagged up duplicates in case of a fail.

Comment: You can't do both at one pass. You need to get rid of the duplicates first. Any other advice from here hinges on this question: why are you creating a PK here? Is it because you feel like you should have one (Answer: don't bother)? Or because it really should be the PK based on requirements and design (Answer: sorry, you have to roll up your sleeves and clean out the dups)? Or because you need to speed up a query (Answer: use a regular index instead)? Something else?

Comment: PKs are required to enable fast table comparison. Tables are generated by two different processes old and new. Those processes appear not to be perfect but at the same time we want to know how they fare against each other after dupes are removed.

Comment: Got it. You don't need a PK for that. Just use a regular index. MySQL doesn't have a preference for which type of index it uses to optimize. It looks at all index types (PK, unique, "regular") and picks the best one(s). And a "regular" index along `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5` will also optimize the query above that finds duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you define a primary key constraint on multiple columns you have to name the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_table PRIMARY KEY (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5);
```

Comment: Thanks Jay for taking time to write it. See my question again please, issue is this cannot be completed due to duplicates in table.

Comment: No. It does not have but due to duplicate rows it cannot be completed. So, the idea is to make an attempt to add it and then using the error find the offended row.

Comment: ok I was confused then, did @Ed's count greater than 1 suggestion help?

Comment: wait you don't want to find duplicates using count?

Comment: I would go with finding duplicates, but issue is with very large tables query would run for hours on Jenkins and we do not have enough stable environment to keep up with it.